# Share a vpn connection from a virtual machine with windows 7 to the host

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, virtualbox, vpn

I need to connect to a Junos Pulse vpn and due configurations of the vpn this is possible only on windows and Mac the problem is I have Linux so I install virtualbox and virtual machine with Windows 7 and do the connection in there. I want to share the vpn connection to the Linux host. How can I make it?

Comment: Yes, this can be done, but it requires much work. Have you seen this instead?  https://alexeymoseyev.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/junos-pulse-vpn-client-on-linux-two-phase-auth-64bit-how-to-make-it-all-work/

Comment: yes I tried it but the vpn has a host checker that checks for the OS of the host trying to connect and for example if is windows checks that has antivirus and other stuff, this checker also check if the OS is Linux then don't allows to do the connection

Comment: No, it only checks the UserAgent of your Browser. If you are using firefox or chrome, you can change it with a downloadable app which will make it look like you are on Windows. Also, you can always run this from within Wine.

Comment: thank you @MariusMatutiae i will try with wine and changing the UserAgent